# Positioning a form over an image

Tags: html, css, image, forms, positioning

I have this html for an image I have placed at the top of my website(I'm working off of local files, the website is not live yet, just messing around first):

HTML:

```
<img id="top-header" src="images/top_header.jpg">
```

CSS:

```
#top-header {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0%;
   top: 0;
}
```

The image is a **3000X200** jpg image

I have a form that I want to place right on top of that image, to the very far right side of the image.

(FORM) HTML:

```
<form id="searchbox" action="" method="get">
<input >
```

[image]

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Set the background of a `div` to the image instead of using the `img` tag then put the form in that.

Comment: for doing that I gues it's gonna take a lot of efforts for you to set all elements in place. Why not Just Make a complete form and then go for styling it.

Comment: I highly second what JimJimmy1995 said.

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal what do you mean by a complete form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same with the form just vary the left to where you want it to load.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/vV2ce/

CSS:

```
#top-header {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0;
}

#searchbox {
    position:absolute; 
    left: 1200px;
    display:inline-block;
    z-index:10
}

/* in my example #searchbox and form are the same so this depends on your overall '
   implementation 

   form {position:absolute; left: 1200px;display:inline-block;z-index:10}
*/
```

HTML:

```
<img id="top-header" src="http://placehold.it/1440x200">

<form id="searchbox" action="" method="get">
   Input <input type="text" />
</form>
```

Comment: It is all css. The html is the same as in the question and viewable at the demo link.

Comment: @SethUrquhart That is Css. If you do not understand that, I guess you should go through http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp first before asking questions here. We recomend that you do a bit of research before asking someone to Help.

Comment: Is the form an "id" or "class". Sorry I understand basic css, I just wasn't sure how the form was connected to the html?

Comment: `form` is an element.  You can apply css styles to all elements that are `form` by that code.  If it had an id like this `<form id="myform" >` you could change the css to `#myform` in this case OR `form#myform` or in your case `#searchbox`  I've updated my answer to use your id since you seem more comfortable with that.

Comment: I'm sorry I made a mistake the image is 3000X200. Sorry, your helping a ton!

Comment: Then you just need to change the left coordinate of the form to match whatever it is you want.

Comment: Ok whatever I change it to, it moves everething to the left that many pixels escept fot the images. I just added 'Top: 0' to the '#searchbox' and it placed the form exactly where I wanted it, but it dragged all my posts with it and my navigation bar.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28272/discussion-between-seth-urquhart-and-lucuma)

Answer (score 2):

Why do you set `position: absolute;` if you just position it on top and left zero? Are there containers with `position: relative;` ?

Just set the form to `position: absolute;` and position it top and left to `0`.

Both, the image and the form need to be in the same container, i.e.:

```
<div id="container">
    <img/>
    <form></form>
</div>
```

with the css:

```
 #container {
     position: relative;
 }

 form {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
 }
```

Another very good alternative would be to use a background-image, as suggested in the comments. In that case you wouldn't need a container or positioning or an image:

```
form {
    background: #FFF url('path/to/image') no-repeat top left;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I am very new to this. What is a container? BTW when I got rid of the 'left: 0%' the image moved to the right about 3 pixels or so. I set it at zero to solve that problem.

Comment: just some sort of HTML-element, it could also be the body itself. You don't really need `position: absolute;` on your image. Just make sure to load a [reset-css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to even out unwanted browser formats.

Comment: I used position: absoluts; on my image so I could keep it out of all my other code. Let me give you a screenshot of my site so you can see what I'm also dealing with...

Comment: @SethUrquhart every browser applies its own css before you apply any style to an element. Google a bit to find how to reset browser styles..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an img tag, a better way is to set the image as the background of the form.

```
form {
   background: url('imagepath.png') no-repeat 0 0;
   text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution too but you'll need to make sure and set the width and height of the form.

Comment: The only reason I don't want to do it this way is that I want to have the image stand alone from the form. I want the form to be apart of the image rather than the image apart of the form. Thanks for the suggestion!